# Parse error from W3C Validator on CSS3 Responsive font titles

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I'm getting an error

> Value Error : font-size Parse Error )/(1600-300)))

from https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator on every line of code below. 
Code is working, CSSlint doesn't report an error, googling hasn't helped.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

```css
h1.page-title { font-size:calc(30px + (30 - 6)*((100vw - 300px)/(1600-300)));font-weight: 400;letter-spacing: 0.015em !important  }
h2.entry-title { font-size:calc(28px + (28 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em !important  }
h3.entry-title { font-size: calc(24px + (24 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em !important  }
h4.entry-title { font-size: calc(20px + (20 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em  !important  }
h5.entry-title { font-size: calc(17px + (17 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em  !important  }
h1 { font-size:calc(28px + (28 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em !important  }
h2 { font-size: calc(24px + (24 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em !important  }
h3 { font-size: calc(20px + (20 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em  !important  }
h4 { font-size: calc(17px + (17 - 6)*((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300))); font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: 0.015em  !important  }
```

Comment: try to add spacing on your first line at this part `(1600-300)` just like with others

Comment: I tried that, didn't make a difference


1 h1.page-title Value Error : font-size Parse Error )/(1600 - 300)))


2 h2.entry-title Value Error : font-size Parse Error (1600 - 300)))```

Answer (score 1):

The w3 validator refers to the [CSS Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#calc-syntax):

> In addition, whitespace is required on both sides of the + and -
>   operators. (The * and / operaters can be used without white space
>   around them.)

So you should add the whitespaces before and after the `(1600-300)` like mentioned by JkAlombro if you want to be spec-compliant. It still works without white spaces in browsers, as they are fault tolerant and implement less strict parsers.

Comment: Thanks, yet I'm unclear what exactly I should be changing, trying a few different options with various whitespace added made no difference, and the above which I assumed meant add space to "(1600-300)" i.e. "(1600 - 300)" like others, also returned errors.